# Select MySQL data starting from a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have player statistics which I would like to publish from certain dates.
At the moment I can see statistics in the database from the beginning.

```
SELECT name, 
       bankmoney AS Bank,
       Playerkills AS 'Player Kills',
       deathcount AS Deaths ,
       aikills AS 'AI Kills',
       teamkills AS 'Team Kills',
       revivecount AS Revives ,
       capturecount AS 'Territories Captured',
       LastModified AS 'Last Seen'
FROM playerinfo
JOIN playerstats
ON playerinfo.UID = playerstats.PlayerUID
ORDER BY BankMoney DESC;
```

But I would like to present statistics from the start of the day and the start of the week.

How would I do that ?

Comment: What is the name of your date column if any?  Do you want from the start of the week to the present, or is there another end date?

Comment: Also what day of the week do you consider to be the first day of the week? Not all systems assume Monday to be the first day of the week.

Comment: I was thinking of using the system time to select Monday as the start of the week. There is no date column.

Comment: So every monday it just counts back one week. Same for day. If it's past midnight everything from then to current time is counted and reported.

Comment: Are you counting back one week regardless of what the day of the week is or simply going from the Monday of the current week up to the current day?

Comment: Thinking about it .. it should just count back one week from what ever day the user requests the data. That would give them  the last 7days stats. Same for day. What ever time they call it just gives them the last 24hours Stats.

Comment: I am still not getting what is being done here ? I have tried putting that line at the end and it produces an error ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Spitfire's comments, to get the last 24 hours of data you can use `INTERVAL` and go back the required number of days you want. `NOW()` will give you the time the query was executed and BETWEEN will allow you to search between two days. So that part of the query could be:

```
WHERE 'Last Seen' BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

A week would require a change from 1 day to 7.

Comment: I have tried this. select name, bankmoney as Bank, Playerkills as 'Player Kills',deathcount as Deaths ,aikills as 'AI Kills',teamkills as 'Team Kills',revivecount as Revives ,capturecount as 'Territories Captured', LastModified as 'Last Seen'
from playerinfo
join playerstats
on playerinfo.UID = playerstats.PlayerUID
order by BankMoney DESC;
WHERE 'Last Seen' BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() INTERVAL - 7 DAY; But it says there is an error. I am not very good at SQL

Comment: What is the error? Also maybe put the `WHERE` clause before the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: The error is Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERVAL - 7 DAY' at line 5 0.110 sec

Comment: Sorry I just spotted that the operator should have preceded the `INTERVAL` keyword rather than come after it. I've edited my answer accordingly. Did you try putting the `WHERE` clause before the `ORDER BY` clause?

Answer (score 1):

Try it.`SELECT * from table_name where a.exam_date BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2;`

Answer (score 0):

for example if you want to see only statistics with lastModified greater or equal today just add a where clause:

```
WHERE 'Last Seen' >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: I don't want to add a date in every time. I was hoping that I could use the system time somehow

Comment: Sorry i dont get your comment, you can use the system time of course.

Comment: How would I do that ?

Comment: for ex. in php you can use the date function date("Y-m-d"), it will return the current date, you can insert the value in your mysql query. You can also do it directly in mysql like WHERE 'Last Seen' >  CURRENT_DATE()
Whatever choice you pick, just make sure the timezone is consistent with what you want to display.

Comment: Humm.. yours is the closest answer, in that yours actually does not have syntax errors. But it is still not quite what I am trying to do. I don't want to have to put dates in manually anywhere ? Does this make sense ?

Comment: Yes if you look at my previous comment I provide two ways to generate the date automaticaaly isnt it? For example just replace the date '2015-04-29' in my answer by CURRENT_DATE()